# Chance of finding cattle in streams

Tags: probability

Last year I went fishing and crossed 4 farms to fish 4 different rivers.  On 3 occasions I saw cattle in the river.  Given there are 15,000 dairy farms in New Zealand I would like to understand the probability of my discovering 3 out of 4 farms with cattle in the river if:

1. There were only 3 farms out of 15,000 in NZ with cattle in the river.
2. There were only 100 farms out of 15,000 in NZ with cattle in the river.
3. There were only 1,000 farms out of 15,000 in NZ with cattle in the river.

Apologies if this is a rewrite of earlier probability questions and that my maths stopped at age 17.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as sampling without replacement where you have sampled (visited) $4$ farms and observed $3$ with cattle in the river. In general, if there are $N$ farms in total, $K$ of them have cattle in the river, and you visit $n$ farms, the probability that you will find exactly $k$ farms with cattle in the river is given by

$$\color{blue}{\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}}.$$

(This is the probability mass function of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).)

For your particular scenario, you have $n=4$ (since you visited $4$ farms), $k=3$ (since you found $3$ farms with cattle in the river), and $N = 15000$ (total number of farms in New Zealand). For your questions 1-3, we have $K=3,100,1000$ respectively, since $K$ represents the number of farms that have cattle in the river. Substitute these values of $n,k,N,K$ into the blue formula above to calculate your desired probabilities.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I shall have a play with the formula,  David

Comment: OK, I have got the following results: For K=3 it is7.11 x 10e-12, for K=100 it is 1.14 x 10e-6 and for 1,000 farms it is 0.0011.  Cheers all